# Sublime Text 3: How to change the highlight of color scheme

Tags: sublimetext3

When I click a word, it highlights the other words which matches it likeit shows below in the image. But this color is very light and it's hard to recognise. How do I change the color of the text hightlighted ?

[image: Screenshot where the word 'files' is highlighted]

Note : I am worried about second and third highlighted words.